# Outlook logon error in csharp

Tags: c#, process, outlook

I use this code to check if the Outlook application is open and if not create a new process and logon.

```
try
{                
    Outlook.Application oApp = null;
    if (System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("OUTLOOK").Count() > 0)
    {
        oApp = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application") as Outlook.Application;
    }
    else oApp = new Outlook.Application();                

    Outlook.NameSpace oNS = oApp.GetNamespace("mapi");                        
    oNS.Logon(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, false, true);

    return oNS.CurrentUser.Name;
}
catch (Exception exp)
{
    Logger.AddMessage(exp.ToString());
}
```

If the program is open I have no issues but when try to start it in csharp I get this logon error:

```
"The server is not available. Contact your administrator if this condition persists."
```

Something missed or what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First set the third parameter to true to see the available profiles to select, then set the default profile name!

```
void Logon(
    Object Profile,
    Object Password,
    Object ShowDialog,
    Object NewSession
)
```

In my case:

```
oNS.Logon("Default Outlook Profile", "", false, true);
```